# Button doing on_release action twice in kivy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to make an app that can automate an Instagram page, and I have the script for the program ready, but just need to implement it into a GUI. For this, I'm using Kivy. However, I only need to send one request to the API for this. When I click on a button, it triggers the command attached to on_release of the button twice. How can I fix this?

Simplified Python Script:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder


class StartScreen(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class BruhApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file("bruh.kv")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BruhApp().run()
```

.kv File:

```
WindowManager:
    StartScreen:

<StartScreen>:
    name: "start"
    FloatLayout:

        MDLabel:
            text: "Welcome to the Instagram Page Automator!"
            font: "RobotoThin"
            font_style: "H5"
            halign: "center"
            size_hint:0.9,0.7
            color: 0,0,0,0.5
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"y":0.5}


        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            md_bg_color: 0, 1, 0.6, 1
            text:"Continue"
            font: "RobotoThin"
            size_hint:0.4,0.07
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"y":0.1}
            on_release:
                print("yes")
```

This script prints "Yes" twice for me everytime I press the button.

Answer (score 2):

The kivy system automatically loads a `kv` file for an `App` if the file is correctly named (See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv)). Since your `kv` file is correctly named, it will be loaded automatically. But since you also load it explicitly using the line:

```
self.root = Builder.load_file("bruh.kv")
```

the `kv` file actually gets loaded twice, which causes some things to be instantiated twice. Try replacing the `build()` method with a simple `pass`.